# flash paths binding, constants

Tags: flash, path, actionscript-2, bind

is it possible to use string as path ?

instead of `_parent._parent.myVar=123;`

use something like this:

`var path = '_parent._parent';`

and then use it as

`path.myVar=123';`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use multiple `[]`.

for your example, you need `_parent._parent`:

```
var path = '_parent';
this[path][path].myVar = 123;
```

another example:

```
var path1 = '_parent';
var path2 = 'apple';
this[path1][path2].myVar = 456;
//equals to _parent.apple.myVar = 456;
```